# Allow inner div inside a div with fixed width to have a 100% width

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve the same thing  **[IN THIS EXAMPLE](http://www.ezpzhosting.co.uk/)** ...i want my navigation to be like on that website.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#nav {
    width: 100%
    background: #585858;
    height: 37px;
}
```

I'm tryting to get the same effect as `repeat-x;` for the nav

Comment: what is your problem..you didnt mention that

Comment: the #nav should break the width of the container e.g width: 980px. the #nav should not have the same width of the container. So in short having the same effect of repeat-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to achieve something like this: **http://jsbin.com/oWeKiqa/2/**

Try this on your CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #585858;
    height: 37px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#container
{
  width:980px;
}
#nav{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  /*...no need of width:100%;..*/
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Du8vZ/1/)**

Comment: Well it does not work. It's still the same width as the container

Comment: here it is..watch out

Comment: Thanks for the idea not using the width: 100%

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to container div and don't forget that you have a typo as you forget to add `;` at the end of `width` property so its not being applied.

[**http://jsbin.com/efilOSA/1/**](http://jsbin.com/efilOSA/1/)